# Localstorage - Set Item with JSON Parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Using JS code, I can able to get Element1 enabled status true or false.

But on load, I want to change the status of enabled = true. When I use below to set item, getting syntax error. Not sure which one is missing out.

```js
let getElement1Status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset')).Element1.enabled;
        if(getElement1Status){
            $('#div-ele').show();
        } else {
            $('#div-ele').hide();
    }
    
    
 JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true')).Element1.enabled;
```

```js
{
   "element1":{
      "enabled":false
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in the line.

Use this -

```
localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true');
```

instead

```
 JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true')).Element1.enabled;
```

You should not use `JSON.parse` while setting `localStorage`

## Update

As per comment seems you want to set Object in storage, please follow the below code for the same.

```
let obj = {cookieset: {Element1: {enabled: true}}};
localStorage.setItem('cookieset', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true') this code - Removes my JSON format completely and overwrite with true. But, i need to change status within "element1" enabled: true

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.setItem` return void, you can not use to `JSON.parse`.

Change your code to

```
 localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true')
 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset')).Element1.enabled;
```

```js
let getElement1Status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset')).Element1.enabled;
        if(getElement1Status){
            $('#div-ele').show();
        } else {
            $('#div-ele').hide();
    }
    
    
 localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true')
 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset')).Element1.enabled;
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true') this code - Removes my JSON format completely and overwrite with true. But, i need to change status within "element1" enabled: true

Answer (score 0):

1. `localStorage.setItem` doesn't return anything so you can not use `JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('cookieset', 'true')).Element1.enabled;`, it will always throw `exception`.
2. If your `element1` is like `element1 = {"enabled": false}` then you can save it into `localStorage` with `localStorage.setItem('cookieset', JSON.stringify(element1));`. **note** in `localStorage` value is being saved as `string` so you need to convert your object to `string` with `JSON.stringify(element1)`.
3. While `fetching` value from `localStorage` you need to use `let getElement1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset'));`. **note** As `localStorage` value is `string` you need to parse it back to object with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset'))`.
4. It is also possible that `localStorage` do not already have that object (in case of page is loading very first time) then it will return `null` value. So you need to update your `if` condition to be like `if (getElement1 && getElement1.enabled) { ... }`

```js
let element1 = {
  "enabled": false
};

let getElement1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookieset'));
if (getElement1 && getElement1.enabled) {
  $('#div-ele').show();
} else {
  $('#div-ele').hide();
}

localStorage.setItem('cookieset', JSON.stringify(element1));
```